# Working with Nullable types in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, nullable

I have Nullable properties defined in my class which take part in calculations and xml writing. As you all know, when any null value takes part in a calculation, the result is always null. I will explain it by examle ::

Code for properties and calculation :

```
public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
public decimal? VatAmount { get; set; }
public decimal? InvoiceAmount { get; set; }
.
.
public decimal Add()
{
     //HERE I NEED 0 TO PERFORM THE CALCULATION
     this.InvoiceAmount = this.Amount + this.VatAmount;
     return this.InvoiceAmount
}
.
.
public string Insert()
{
     XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(@"Transactions.xml");
        var record = from r in doc1.Descendants("Transaction")
                     where (int)r.Element("Serial") == Serial
                     select r;
        foreach (XElement r in record)
        {
             //HERE I WANT NULL VALUES RETAINED  
             r.Element("DebitNote").Add(new XElement("InvoiceAmount", this.InvoiceAmount), new XElement("VatAmount", this.VatAmount), new XElement("Amount", this.Amount));
        }
        doc2.Save(@"Transactions.xml");
        return "Invoice Created Successfully";
```

As you can see until the value of **Amount** or **VatAmount** is null, the **InvoiceAmount** will always be null. How can i work around this ??. One possible solution is to set the default value of private variable of **Amount** and **VatAmount** equal to **0**. But with this setting when i add record to xml, the value for **Amount** and **InvoiceAmount** will be entered 0; whereas i want to retain null if nothing is entered in this case.

Let me know how can both conditions be satisfied. **Don't necessarily need to write code, can tell me in General**

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: ***SLaks and Klaus answers are the optimal solution, guess StackOverFlow can think of allowing users to mark more than one answers if possible*** 

t

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write `Amount ?? 0`.
This code uses the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), which evaluates to its first non-null operand.

Thus, `Amount ?? 0` will evaluate to `Amount` if it's non-null and `0` if it is null.

Comment: Thanks Slaks....Your solution too is good but i will opt for Klaus as i have too much properties to use null-coalescing operator. Thanks Buddy

Comment: @Pankaj: What do you mean? You can write `Amount ?? 0 + VatAmount ?? 0`.

Comment: ohh k......sorry sorry....actually i thought you meant to say i should use this while defining.....I guess thats a tie between you and Klaus..... I am not able to mark more than one answer ??.....

Comment: : You missed an important thing which kept me confused the last whole day. Or may be i was stupid not to make notice :P..... Your code `Amount ?? 0 + VatAmount ?? 0` will always output **Amount** when Amount has value, irrespective of whether VatAmount contains anything or not. The small editing required to make this code work is `InvoiceAmount = (Amount ?? 0) + (VatAmount ?? 0) ;`

Answer (score 6):

How about using the `GetValueOrDefault` method of `Nullable<T>` in the calculation? This way you will get zeroes for your calculation but retain the nulls for your xml.

```
this.InvoiceAmount = this.Amount.GetValueOrDefault() 
                   + this.VatAmount.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Comment: @Daniel: I'm pretty sure [it's been there all along](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: @Daniel, `GetValueOrDefault` was there in the first version of `Nullable<T>` which was introduced in .Net 2.0.

Comment: Thanks Buddy, I think this is the best/optimal solution. By this way, i don't need to use conditional statements for individual properties which is tough as i have 40 properties in all :-) ... Thanks so so much

Answer (score 1):

```
if (this.Amount.HasValue) 
    this.InvoiceAmount += this.Amount;
if (this.VatAmount.HasValue) 
    this.InvoiceAmount += this.VatAmount;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think `InvoiceAmount` will also have to be set to 0 first (before either of the `+=` ops) or else the result will still evaluate to `null` in each case.

Comment: Plus the if statement can actually be shortened into the more readable and succinct examples from Klaus and SLaks.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.....I too think Klaus answer is the best suitable.....Your case can be noticed, if there are few properties to work with.....

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to check for null in you add method and treat it as zero.

eg:

```
//HERE I NEED 0 TO PERFORM THE CALCULATION
 this.InvoiceAmount = this.Amount ?? decimal.Zero + this.VatAmount ?? decimal.Zero;
 return this.InvoiceAmount
```

Comment: Damn, wish I could type faster, keep missing out!

Comment: It's good when i have less properties .... But it's the right answer too.... Thanks **Wraith**